# Can an on-prem solution of SharePoint 2013 or 2016 be hosted in a docker/windows container?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016

I am trying to find a way to quickly deploy new SharePoint On-Prem solutions for both 2013 and 2016, but I am having a terribly hard time finding any literature to help make this a possibility.  Ideally, I'd like to not have to worry about setting up SharePoint every time.

Is this feasible?

NOTE: I am not looking to use SharePoint Framework...just SharePoint 2013 or 2016 on prem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am quite sure that you currently are NOT able to set this up because SharePoint on-prem requires AD accounts for the various services to run. You can neither run a domain controller on a docker container for Windows nor connect to a domain controller running outside of the container - if I understand this correctly. Have a look at this thread on StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677018/active-directory-accounts-inside-a-windows-container-server-2016-tp5

**Update 2018-10-26**

I just stumbled across this blog describing how the local service account on a docker container can be mapped to 'external' AD accounts. I am not sure, but this might be something worth trying with SharePoint on-prem.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/01/30/create-a-container-with-active-directory-support/

Comment: any updates since 2017 anyone? Google searches aren't looking too encouraging yet. There is some stuff out there not sure how useful it is